# Check unread mail counts in multiple exchange accounts simultaneously

Tags: email, exchange-2003

I help manage an Exchange 2003 server for a local school. The school principal recently instituted a policy stating that all teachers need to check their email at least once a day. As (one of) the Exchange admins, I want to know if there's a way I can check up to see whether folks are following this policy.

I figure I would need to see two things:

1. unread counts for all mailboxes on the Exchange server
2. for the unread messages, I want to see the date the message was sent

In talking to the school IT consultant, I was told that there's no way to do this using Exchange. **Are any of you familiar with a way to accomplish this?**

BTW, if this can be solved via a cron-like script which gets all counts & dates, sticks it in a text file, and emails it to me, that's fine also. Whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for this type of thing is to discover the Windows Powershell.  Unfortunately, although it seems the work [has been done for you](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2007/05/unread-email-report-for-all-folders-in.html), the learning curve is rather steep and it is unlikely there exists a single line answer for your needs.

I suggest you start with [MSDN's getting started guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757(VS.85).aspx), followed by [the official Powershell blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, I actually posted a link to that exact blog post, and when I read your response I was wondering where my response had gone. Turns out I posted it in the wrong thread... stupid me. This definitely seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's low-tech (and cludgy) but if your goal is to see who's logged on and when, that's available in System Manager under administrative groups[org_name]\servers[server_name]\first storage group\mailbox store\logons

That'll tell you recent logon dates & times.  I'd imagine you can check that at the end of the day and see who hasn't accessed their mailbox within 8 hours.

If it's not scriptable, you can export that list from the context menu, but ugh... I hope somebody has a more automated solution.

Comment: Do you know if that would record users logging on through the Exchange web interface? If not, this won't work; many teachers check mail from home.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the log (properties on the serverin system manager to get the location) tracks OWA access.